# Management of notification icons on the app icon in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uilocalnotification

when trying out notifications, two message icons are displayed on the app icon, how will they be deleted? It would also be an advantage if you can go to a certain view so that it can be deleted.

Thank you

Comment: You can control the application badge (if that’s what you mean) using the UIApplication object

Comment: Ok how exactly? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: I've already told you where to look (use `UIApplication` to set the `badge` value). It's not something hard to do, you'll learn much more if you search and figure it out on your own that if I give you the exact code.

Comment: Ok, thank you(you have right).